Does Gaussian heat kernel ensure $\int_{\mathbb R^d} (1+|x|) \sqrt{\ell_{t_0} (x)} \, \mathrm d x < \infty$?
$
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
$
Let $\ell : \bR^d \to \bR_+$ be a probability density function such that
$$
\int_{\bR^d} (1+|x|) \sqrt{\ell (x)} \diff x < \infty.
$$
Let $(p_t)_{t>0}$ be the standard Gaussian heat kernel on $\bR^d$, i.e.,
$$
p_t (x) := \frac{1}{(4 \pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}} \exp \left ( -\frac{|x|^2}{4 t} \right ).
$$
We denote by $*$ the mollification operation and let $\ell_t := \ell * p_t$. Now we fix $t_0 >0$.

Is it true that
$$
\int_{\bR^d} (1+|x|) \sqrt{\ell_{t_0} (x)} \diff x < \infty \, ?
$$

Thank you for your elaboration.

Hm, I merely changed the typo in the title, and now the edit history attributes a very different edit to me, which I did not make...

@gmvh I made an edit at the same time as yours, which may be the reason...

Unless I made an error on my napkin, this is not even true "without the $\sup$". Do you have evidence for the finiteness of $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (1+|x|) \sqrt{\ell_t (x)} \mathrm{d}x$ for fixed $t \in (0, 1]$?

@unwissen You are right. It should be my first question. I have edited my thread accordingly.

Consider $$\ell = \sum_{n} c_n \mathbb{1}_{A_n}$$ for some $c_n > 0$ and disjoint intervals $A_n = [x_n, x_n + b_n]$ with $x_n, b_n > 0$ to be determined later.
Then you want
$$
    \int \, \ell(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
    = \sum_{n} c_n \vert A_n \vert
    = \sum_{n} c_n b_n
    < +\infty
$$ and also
$$
    \int \, (1+\vert x\vert) \sqrt{\ell(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
    = \sum_{n} \sqrt{c_n}  \int_{x_n}^{x_n + b_n} \, \mathrm{d}x (1+x)
    \leq \sum_{n} \sqrt{c_n} b_n (1+x_n + b_n)
    \lesssim \sum_{n} \sqrt{c_n}  b_n x_n
    < +\infty
$$
For all $n$ and $x \in (x_n - 1, x_n + 1)$ we have
$$  (\ell \ast p_t)(x) 
    \gtrsim_t \int_{x-1}^{x+1}  \, \ell(y) \mathrm{d}y
    \gtrsim c_n \vert A_n \vert 
    = c_n b_n,
$$ i.e.
$$
    \int \, \mathrm{d}x \, (1+\vert x\vert) \, \sqrt{\ell_t(x)}
    \gtrsim \sum_n \sqrt{c_n} \sqrt{b_n} \int_{x_n - 1}^{x_n + 1} \, \mathrm{d}x \, (1+ x)
    \gtrsim \sum_n \sqrt{c_n} \sqrt{b_n} x_n
$$
Can you find $x_n, b_n, c_n$ to produce a counterexample?

Thank you very much for your informative answer. The nonlinearity makes good things fail

No problem :) Though I don't think it is just "nonlinearity". The statement would be true for the still very nonlinear $\vert \cdot \vert^p$ (p>1) in place of $\sqrt{\cdot}$.
