Hölder continuity in time of heat semigroup
$
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
$
We fix $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ and $c>0$. Let $\ell : \bR^d \to \bR_+$ be a probability density function such that
$$
\|\ell\|_{\infty} + \sup_{\substack{x, y \in {\bR}^d \\ x \neq y}} \frac{| \ell (x)-\ell (y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} + \int_{\bR^d} |x| \ell (x) \diff x  \le c.
$$
Let $(p_t)_{t>0}$ be the standard Gaussian heat kernel on $\bR^d$, i.e.,
$$
p_t (x) := \frac{1}{(4 \pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}} \exp \left ( -\frac{|x|^2}{4 t} \right ).
$$
We denote by $*$ the convolution operation and let $\ell_t := \ell * p_t$.

Is there a constant $c_1>0$ (depending on $d, \alpha, c$) such that we have for $s, t\in [0, 1]$:
$$
 \int_{\bR^d} (1 + |x|) |\ell_t (x) - \ell_s (x)| \diff x \le c_1 |t-s|^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \, ?
$$

Thank you for your elaboration.

Akira, I hope you don't mind if I changed the term "mollification" with the term convolution: strictly speaking the former one is the convolution with a mollifier, i.e. the operator $p_t\ast(\cdot)$.

@DanieleTampieri Thank you for your edit. Indeed, I meant "convolution" rather than "mollification".

Are you willing to assume the additional, stronger condition $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (1+|x|) \sqrt{\ell (x)} \mathrm{d} x < \infty$ as in your other question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/474098/does-gaussian-heat-kernel-ensure-int-mathbb-rd-1x-sqrt-ell-t-0-x ? Then I think the answer is yes, otherwise no because there is no reason for the integral of $\frac{\vert \ell(x + tZ) - \ell(x) \vert)}{\vert t \vert^{\alpha}}$ under $(1+\vert x\vert) \mathrm{d}x$ to be $o(\vert t\vert^{\alpha/2})$ (compare with the situation of an function which is integrable but it's derivative is not)

@unwissen I am willing to assume that stronger condition. I hope you can elaborate on such situation in an answer. I am curious how the detail works out

Please create a new question because this technically answers a different question.

@unwissen I have asked a new question at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/474289/h%c3%b6lder-continuity-in-time-of-heat-semigroup-for-regular-initial-distribution.

No, such a bound is not possible.
We will show a counterexample for $d = 1$. For a given $T \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, consider the following function $\ell^{(T)} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$:
on the interval $x\in [-1,1]$ define $\ell(x) := (1 - |x|)$, on the interval $x\in[2\pi T, 2\pi(T+1)$ define $\ell(x) := (1 + \sin(x T))/T$, on $x \in [2\pi T - 1, 2 \pi T]$ take $\ell(x)$ to linearly interpolate between $0$ and $1/T$, similarly on the interval $x\in [2\pi (T+1), 2\pi (T+1) + 1]$ and finally $\ell(x) = 0$ elsewhere.
Here is the plot of the proposed function (not to scale).

Clearly $\int \ell(x) \mathrm{d} x \in [1, 10]$, similarly $\int |x| \ell(x) \mathrm{d}(x) \in [0.5, 10]$, and $\ell$ is $1$-Lipschitz.
Now, note that for small enough $t$, as long as $T \gg 1/t$, the difference $\ell_t(X) - \ell(X)$ is very close $\sin(xT)/T$ for $x \in [2 \pi T, 2\pi (T+1)]$, and close to zero everywhere else. This is because $\sin(T x)$ is an eigenfunction of a convolution with a Gaussian kernel $p_t$: if $f_T(x) := \sin(T x)$ then $f_T * p_t = \exp(-t^2 T^2) f_T$. Hence $\int |x| |\ell_t^{(T)}(x) - \ell^{(T)}(x)| \mathrm{d}{x} \approx \int_{2 \pi T}^{2\pi(T+1)} |x| |\sin(Tx)|/|T| \mathrm{d} x \geq \Omega(1)$.
For arbitrarily small $t$, we can chose large enough $T \gg 1/t$, such that the integral $\int |x| |\ell^{(T)}_t - \ell^{(T)}_t| \mathrm{d} x\geq C$, where $C$ is a universal constant.

Yes, thanks, it should interpolate between $0$ and $1/T$ there. I think it's supposed to be $sin(xT)/T$ on the interval $[2 \pi T, 2\pi (T+1)]$, though (the function is supposed have very high oscillations, so that convolution with gaussian of width much larger than wavelength averages it out to zero).

Yes, sorry, the other correction was nonsense, of course it has to be like this for the derivative to have high mass. Again, a very nice example.
