Hölder continuity in time of heat semigroup for regular initial distribution
$
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
$
Let $(p_t)_{t>0}$ be the standard Gaussian heat kernel on $\bR^d$, i.e.,
$$
p_t (x) := \frac{1}{(4 \pi t)^{\frac{d}{2}}} \exp \left ( -\frac{|x|^2}{4 t} \right ).
$$
We fix $\alpha \in (0, 1)$ and $c>0$. Let $\ell : \bR^d \to \bR_+$ be a probability density function such that
$$
\|\ell\|_{\infty} + \sup_{\substack{x, y \in {\bR}^d \\ x \neq y}} \frac{| \ell (x)-\ell (y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} + \int_{\bR^d} (1+|x|) \sqrt{\ell (x)} \diff x  \le c.
$$
We denote by $*$ the convolution operation and let $\ell_t := \ell * p_t$.

Is there a constant $c_1>0$ (depending on $d, \alpha, c$) such that we have for $s, t\in [0, 1]$:
$$
\int_{\bR^d} (1 + |x|) |\ell_t (x) - \ell_s (x)| \diff x \le c_1 |t-s|^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \, ?
$$

Thank you for your elaboration.

I believe so.
Let $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
Then
$$
 \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{d}x \,(1 + |x|) \, \vert \ell_{t} (x) - \ell_{s} (x) \vert
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{d}x \,(1 + |x|) \, \left\vert \mathbb{E}\left[\ell(x + tZ) \right] - \mathbb{E}\left[\ell(x + sZ) \right]  \right\vert \\
\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{d}x \,(1 + |x|) \,  \mathbb{E}\left[\left\vert \ell(x + tZ) - \ell(x + sZ)\right\vert\right] 
= \mathbb{E}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{d}x \,(1 + |x|) \,  \left\vert \ell(x + tZ) - \ell(x + sZ)\right\vert\right] \\
= \vert t-s\vert^{\alpha/2} \, \mathbb{E}\left[\vert Z\vert^{\alpha/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{d}x \, (1 + |x|)    \left(\frac{\vert \ell(x + tZ) - \ell(x + sZ) \vert}{\vert (x + tZ) - (x+sZ) \vert^\alpha}\right)^{1/2} \vert \ell(x + tZ) - \ell(x + sZ) \vert^{1/2} \right] \\
\leq c^{1/2} \vert t-s\vert^{\alpha/2} \, \mathbb{E}\left[\vert Z\vert^{\alpha/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{d}x \,(1 + |x|) \,    \left(\vert \ell(x + tZ) \vert^{1/2} + \vert\ell(x + sZ) \vert^{1/2}\right) \right] \\
=   c^{1/2} \vert t-s\vert^{\alpha/2} \, \mathbb{E}\left[\vert Z\vert^{\alpha/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{d}x \,(1 + |x-tZ|) \,    \vert \ell(x) \vert^{1/2} + \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{d}x \,(1 + |x - sZ|) \, \vert\ell(x) \vert^{1/2}\right] \\
\leq  c^{1/2} \vert t-s\vert^{\alpha/2} \, \mathbb{E}\left[\vert Z\vert^{\alpha/2} \, 2(1+\vert Z\vert) \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{d}x \,(1 + |x|) \, \vert\ell(x) \vert^{1/2}\right] \\
\leq \left( 2 c^{1/2} c \mathbb{E}\left[\vert Z\vert^{\alpha/2} (1+\vert Z\vert) \right] \right) \vert t-s\vert^{\alpha/2}.
$$

Thank you very much for your recent comments and answers.

@Akira hope it helps :)
